# Eclipse: how to hide custom files in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a custom builder in CDT, which adds alot of files into project directory. I want those files to be filtered out from Project Explorer, but cannot figure out how (the file mask is *.ooj).

Is it possible to add a custom filter by file mask into Customize View? Or maybe there is anther way to hide files in Project Explorer?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here's how to do it on Eclipse Indigo/Luna/Neon (as of 2018-05-22):

- Open the "project properties"

  - pull down menu --> Project --> Properties
  - A new dialog window named "Properties" will appear
- Create a "Resource Filter"

  - Select Resource --> Resource Filters -> Add Filter...
  - A new dialog window named "Add Resource Filter for project" will appear
  - In the new dialog select the following

    - Filter Type: Exclude All
    - Applies to: Files
    - **Make sure to click the checkbox for "All children (recusive)"**
    - File and Folder Attributes

      - select: Name
      - select: Matches
      - fill in: *.ooj
    - Click OK
    - Dialog closes
- Apply the new filter

  - Click Apply
  - You should see a change in your "Navigator" View
- Close the "Project Properties"

  - Click OK
- Done

Comment: When I do this, my folder get hidden but immediately it appears again. What can I do?

Comment: If you'd like to do that for all projects you can click on the pointing-down triangle in the package explorer bar (next to the minimize icon), and select Filters from there. Then just add your filter (you can use regex) to the top textarea.

Comment: Does not work on Indigo. Seemed to work once. But now it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

**How to add global user defined resource filters to the Eclipse Project Explorer view:**

Modifying and switching filters on a project level needs a lot of clicks and can be tedious if you have many projects in your workspace. If you need to apply or switch the same filter settings on all projects again and again you might prefer a quicker and global solution for all projects and all workspaces.

- Modify the files `plugin.xml` and `plugin.properties` in `plugins/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_{version}.jar` (extract, modify and re-add the modified files).
- For example, add a file only filter in `plugin.xml` to the element `/plugin/extension @point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent"`:

  ```
  <commonFilter id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.{unique-id-a}" name="%filters.{unique-id-a}.name" description="%filters.{unique-id-a}.description" activeByDefault="true|false">
     <filterExpression>
        <and>
           <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
           <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="{file-wildcard-pattern-a}"/>
        </and>
     </filterExpression>
  </commonFilter>
  ```
- As another example, add a file and directory filter in `plugin.xml` to the same element:

  ```
  <commonFilter id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.{unique-id-b}" name="%filters.{unique-id-b}.name" description="%filters.{unique-id-b}.description" activeByDefault="true|false">
     <filterExpression>
        <and>
           <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="{file-wildcard-pattern-b}"/>
           </adapt>
        </and>
     </filterExpression>
  </commonFilter>
  ```
- Provide filter names and descriptions for all added filters in `plugin.properties`. Filter display order in Project Explorer view is by this filter name regardless of filter type:

  ```
  filters.{unique-id-a}.name={file-wildcard-pattern-a} files
  filters.{unique-id-a}.description=Hides files that match "{file-wildcard-pattern-a}"

  filters.{unique-id-b}.name={file-wildcard-pattern-b} files and folders
  filters.{unique-id-b}.description=Hides files and folders that match "{file-wildcard-pattern-b}"
  ```
- Restart Eclipse and reset its caches: `eclipse.exe -clean`

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I was looking for to hide `*.orig` files (from hg/git merges): this worked: `<commonFilter id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.origFiles" name="%filters.origFiles.name" description="%filters.origFiles.description" activeByDefault="false">
      <filterExpression>
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
          <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.orig" />
        </adapt>
      </filterExpression>
    </commonFilter>` for `plugin.xml` and ...

Comment: ... (continued my previous comment) `filters.origFiles.name=*.orig resources
filters.origFiles.description=Hides resources that end with ".orig", e.g. generated on versioning system merges (e.g. Mercurial/HG, GIT)
` for `plugins.properties`. after `eclipse -clean` everything was available in Eclipse Kepler :)

Comment: with the ***Remote Systems* plugin** (maybe already available in your Eclipse distro) this is **quite easy to setup without extra apps ((un)packer, file navigator etc.)**: 1. go to (or *Window -> Show View -> Remote Systems*), 2. *Local -> ... -> org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_<version>.jar -> plugins.xml / plugins.properties -> double click*, 3. edit/insert desired content in both files, 4. *Remote Systems -> ... -> plugins.xml / plugins.properties -> right click -> Synchronize Cache* :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a filter for that. Open the view menu in the Package Explorer and then choose "Filters..." Here you can define a pattern to hide files.

Comment: View Menu has no `Filters` option. I need to click Customize View to access `Filters`. But there are only predefined filters, such as "Archive Files", "Java Files" etc, and no option to add/edit those filters

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: Eclipse 3.7(Indigo) has a customizable filter named "Name filter patterns" in the menu he mentioned, but Juno has removed it as far as I can see. Don't know why either.

Comment: @rmflowless Newer versions use "Project Explorer" by default. You want the "Package Explorer" for that filter.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly thanks to @emmzett
Just wanna explain in a verbose mode of emmzett's answer because I didn't know anything editing plugin files and I spent 2 hours on this. Maybe I can save your time with this clarified expression.

1. Firstly go in eclipse file then
   *plugins->org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_(your eclipse version).jar*
2. Right click to .jar file and open with winrar
3. Find the `plugin.xml` open with an editor(notepad,Notepad++ etc) the
   `plugin.xml` file
4. Find the `point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent"` and paste code below

   ```
   <commonFilter id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType" 
                name="%filters.SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType.name" 
                description="%filters.SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType.description"
                activeByDefault="true">
     <filterExpression>
         <and>
            <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="your specific file"/>
         </and>
      </filterExpression>
   </commonFilter>
   ```
5. Change `SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType` with a unique name for id
   Change `"your specific file"` with your specific file suffix like `*.pdf` or `desktop.ini` etc.
6. Save the `plugin.xml` and exit
7. Find the `plugin.properties` open with an editor same as 3.step
   Paste this code

   ```
   filters.SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType.name=your specific file files
   filters.SpecifyAnIdForYourFileType.description=Hides files that match your specific file
   ```
8. Save `plugin.properties` and exit
9. Restart the eclipse and clear cache than go to `Project Explorer` at
   the left side
10. Click the `View Menu` icon at the top right corner
11. Click the `Filters and Customization...`
12. Tick your new filter in the `Filters` menu.

That's all I want to thanks again to emmzett.

Regards.