# eclipse kepler: how to hide "libraries in project"?

Tags: eclipse

how can I hide jar files in the project explorer? In previous versions of eclipse it was possible to hide them with "libraries in project" filter, but I don't find that anymore in kepler. Now there is only "libraries from external", but that's not enough, I still see a lot of libraries in my project on the top level.

Context: I've imported a play 2.1.3 generated project into eclipse kelper, and I have a lot of jars in the lib folder.

Comment: Have you tried the resource filters on the project properties? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137848/eclipse-how-to-hide-custom-files-in-project-explorer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: the Project Explorer now appears by default.  Open the *Package Explorer* (the old default) in Window/Show View/Other/Java.